# How do I implement a dummy filter to exclude a file from being filtered?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I am trying to implement a filter for all my files excluding login.jsp. I understand that filter mapping cannot exclude certain files. What I need to do is to create another filter to map just the login.jsp. How do I create another file that with url pattern /login.jsp and without SessionFilter being processed after it?
Here is part of my code for session filter for all files.

```
public class SessionFilter implements Filter{ 
   RequestDispatcher rd = null; 

  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) 
   throws IOException, ServletException{ 
      HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)request; 
      HttpSession session = request.getSession(); 

   // New Session so forward to login.jsp 
   if (session.isNew()){ 
     rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp"); 
     rd.forward(request, response); 
  } 

  // Not a new session so continue to the requested resource 
   else{ 
      filterChain.doFilter(request, response); 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the requested path is in your "excluded list" with `request.getServletPath()`.

If you want a new `Filter` separated from `SessionFilter`, you could either set a special flag as request attribute (such as "loginPage") which will be checked by other filters (if you want a new `Filter` separated from `SessionFilter`) or you can simply not invoke the `chain.doFilter()`.

If you're modifying `SessionFilter`, just don't redispatch to "login.jsp"

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not sure how to not invoke chain.doFilter().

Comment: @JustToHelp, simply don't use this statement ;)

Comment: @JustToHelp: you are already doing it at the code you have pasted (the last code line, inside the else block).

Comment: I am trying to redirect users to my login page if there is an invalid session. 

 if(!session.isNew()){
             
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
     else{
            rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
  }

The problem is that if I use requestdispatcher, there will be an infinite loop when the users access login.jsp.

Comment: @JustToHelp, so if `request.getServletPath()` is your login page, don't call the `filterChain.doFilter`, this way other filters won't be called.

Comment: I am modifying my SessionFilter but I am still having the error. 

 String path = req.getServletPath();

if(!session.isNew()){
             
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
        else if(path.indexOf("login.jsp")!=-1){
            //do nothing
        }
     else{
            rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
  }

Comment: If session isn't new (because your didn't go through the login page) the chain will be done, you have to check the servlet path first.

Comment: ah, I see what you mean. But even with checking at the if statement it still cant run. 

 String path = req.getServletPath();
        int a = -1;
          a= path.indexOf("login.jsp");
        HttpSession session = req.getSession();

        if(!session.isNew() ||a==-1){
             
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }

     else{
            rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
  }

Comment: I added a print message inside the if statement. The SessionFilter works, all the other page will print the same message. But how to redirect to login.jsp without causing an infinite loop?

Comment: ok I got it to work by manually inputing the url pattern instead of a generic /*

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a new filter. You could check it at your own filter.

```
if(request.getServletPath().equals("login.jsp") || !session.isNew()) { // or "/login.jsp", not sure about this
   filterChain.doFilter(request, response); 
} else { // session is new and it's not login.jsp
     rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp"); 
     rd.forward(request, response);    
}
```

But I don't like this kind of approach. It seems like rewriting the JAAS API for servlets. And it implies hardcoding jsp paths, which could be not a good idea in order of maintenance and portability.